# Problems with struct of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have a segmentation fault when this code runs, but it compiles without issue.  What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *fld[129];
} isomsg;

void iso8583_init(isomsg *m)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 128; i++) {
        m->fld[i] = NULL;
    }
}


isomsg  m;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    iso8583_init(&m);

    strcpy(m.fld[0],"Fisrt");

    printf("First = %s\n",m.fld[0]);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problematic line is:

```
strcpy(m.fld[0],"Fisrt");
```

`m.fld[0]` is a pointer initialized to NULL. You can't write to the address if its point to NULL. This is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You probably want:

```
m.fld[0] = "Fisrt";
```

This assigns the address of the string literal to the pointer `m.fld[0]`.

Or if you want to make a copy of the string literal `"First"` then you can use `strdup()` (POSIX):

```
m.fld[0] = strdup("Fisrt");
```

Or use `malloc()` + `strcpy()` (in standard C):

```
m.fld[0] = malloc( sizeof("First") ); //allocate memory of 6 bytes
strcpy(m.fld[0], "First");
```

(You should check if [strdup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html)/`malloc()` return NULL due to failure.)

Comment: What about if i use: memcpy(&m.fld[0],"First",5);

Comment: @user5240895 memcpy() is another way to copy. But in any case, you need to have the pointer pointing to valid memory location i.e. you still need to do malloc() on the pointer you pass to memcpy().